# STM32F1xx Hal Driver - Uart Receive IT - HAL_UART_ERROR_FE

Tags: stm32

I get lately a lot the HAL_UART_ERROR_FE (Frame Error). I have no where found what causes this Error in the first place. Can someone explain to me what was going wrong that i get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A framing error can be caused by

- Mismatched bitrate
- Noise on the line
- Starting the receiver while the other endpoint is already transmitting

Comment: Yeah this is probably 3. I use the it mode with 2 chars, as it is used for a terminal input. I use the halfetransmit cb to push the first character into a fifo and the transfer end for the 2nd char to push into the fifo plus activate the it receiving mode again. When now 3 chars are send with one teansmission i get the error. This is really unpractical to use the rx it mode for variable lengths. But i dont want to use polling...

Comment: Is there a better solution to receive with the it mode, get interrupta for each char received and automatically push to a fifo/ringbuffer?

Comment: Yes, there is. Don't use HAL at all, just read `UART->SR` and `UART->DR` in the interrupt handler.